# Cannot concatenate Date and file name for mkdir() JavaFX

Tags: java, date, javafx, concatenation, mkdir

I'm having a problem when I concatenate the Date and the file name for making a new directory.

If I PATH.concat(movie) It creates a directory but if I concat the name (movie name with date) "It says created!" but It doesn't create any directoy.

```
  FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Select a File ('.mp4')", "*.mp4");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            String movie = file.getName();
            filePath = file.toURI().toString();

            String s;
            Format formatter;
            Date date = new Date();

            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
            s = formatter.format(date);

            String PATH = "C:\\FINALDATA\\";
            String name = movie+"("+s+")";

            String folderName = PATH.concat(name);

    File fileName = new File(folderName);       

    if(!fileName.exists()){
        boolean result = fileName.mkdir();
                    System.out.print("Created!");
            }else{
                System.out.print("Error!");
            }
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Noted. Thank you for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is creating the issue here. You cannot create a folder or a file name with `'/'` in it. I think you better change the date format to `MM-dd-yyyy` and try.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu");
    String s = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Bratislava")).format(dateFormatter);
```

This will give you a string `s` like

> 12-09-2018

As UVM already said, the forward slash `/` is a forbidden character in file names on Windows (and on other common operating systems too, along with backward slash `\` and  colon `:`).

You may want to take it one step further and use ISO 8601 format for your date. Then sorting alphabetically is also chronological.

```
    String s = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Bratislava")).toString();
```

> 2018-12-09

Don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes have design problems. In my experience particularly the latter is oftentimes troublesome. The classes are also long outdated. And java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is so much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.